# Prism 5 and Unity - Manually resolve View with ViewModel wired up

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-5

**Using:** WPF, Prism 5, Unity

I am trying to write what I call a "WindowDialogService" which, when passed a type and called, will open a Window with that type as the content. My problem is I cannot get the ViewModel to instantiate and associate to the View.

I don't know if it is right but I am using `AutoWireViewModel` in my View and was assuming (obviously incorrectly) that the ViewModel would be "Located" when resolving using the Unity Container i.e. `container.TryResolve <T> ()`

So basically, I can resolve the View but the DataContext of the view is null.

I have included all relevant code below.

**View**

```
<dxc:DXWindow x:Class="ListClassList.Views.AddToClassView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"      
              prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
              xmlns:dxe="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.Settings;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v15.2"
              xmlns:dxeditors="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
              xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" 
              xmlns:dxgt="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid/themekeys"
             xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"              
             xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                    dxc:ThemeManager.ThemeName="VS2010"
                    Title="{Binding Title}"
                    Width="800"
                    Height="500"
              ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
             >
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</dxc:DXWindow>
```

**ViewModel**

```
using MyApp.Data;
using MyApp.Models.Model;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListClassList.ViewModels
{
    public class AddToClassViewViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly MyAppDbContext _context;

        private ObservableCollection<MasterClass> _masterClasses;
        public ObservableCollection<MasterClass> MasterClasses
        {
            get { return _masterClasses; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _masterClasses, value); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get { return _students; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _students, value);
            }
        }


        public DelegateCommand FinishCommand { get; set; }


        public AddToClassViewViewModel(IStudentTimetableService studentTimetableService)
        {


        }

    }
}
```

**IWindowDialogService Interface**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
    namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.Services.Dialogs.WindowDialog
    {
        public interface IWindowDialogService
        {
            bool? ShowDialog<T>(Action onDialogClosed) where T : Window;
        }
    }
```

**WindowDialogService Implementation**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using Prism.Unity;


namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.Services.Dialogs.WindowDialog
{
    public sealed class WindowDialogService : IWindowDialogService
    {
        private readonly List<Window> _openWindows = new List<Window>();
        private static volatile WindowDialogService _instance;
        private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();

        private WindowDialogService() { }

        public static WindowDialogService Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (SyncRoot)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                            _instance = new WindowDialogService();
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }


        public bool? ShowDialog<T>(Action onDialogClosed) where T : Window
        {
            try
            {
                 using (var container = new Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer())
                {
                    var dialog = (Window)container.TryResolve <T> ();
                    dialog.Closed += (s, e) => onDialogClosed();
                    var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
                    return result;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism 6 does this automatically, for Prism 5 you need something along the lines of

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory( type => Container.Resolve( type ) );
```

in your bootstrapper's `ConfigureContainer`

Comment: Thanks Haukinger. I tried this but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Is there something else I need to change in my code? I put that line of code (exactly as shown) into my ConfigureContainer in my bootstrapper. Is the way I am resolving the view (newing up a UnityContainer and using TryResolve) correct?

Comment: I'd use the one unity container from the bootstrapper (have it injected as dependency of your service), just in case your window has any dependencies of its own. And, of course, all the dependencies of your view model have to be registered with the container used to resolve the view model.

Comment: Ok, my bad! *Dumb* I recently upgraded to Prism 6 which resulted in a breaking change that the View cannot end in "View" (and respectively ViewModels cannot end in "ViewViewModel". See here: github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism. Will be marking yours as correct answer seeing as it does address the question as asked ;-)

Comment: The view can end with `View`, but the view model with end with `ViewModel` (not `ViewViewModel`) then...